# How can Controlled Hadamard be implemented with Q#? Is there an inbuilt function?

Tags: q#

I found a way to implement Controlled Hadamard on https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/proxy/tutorial/full-user-guide/004-Quantum_Algorithms/061-Basic_Circuit_Identities_and_Larger_Circuits.html

Is there an easier way in Q# to implement this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Controlled` functor to produce a controlled version of any operation which allows for that (including primitive gates) as follows:

```
Controlled H([controls], target);
```

You can look up the details of using `Controlled` functor [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/type-model#controlled).